# ConsoleZ maven color output

Tags: windows, maven, console

Recent maven versions do colored output in terminal. Git Bash shows correct colors, but [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console/wiki) configured to use git bash does not. It just outputs raw color codes. Does anyone know how to fix it

```
$ mvn clean
[←[1;34mINFO←[m] Scanning for projects...
[←[1;34mINFO←[m]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same issue in Window10 with Git Bash in both Console2 and ConsoleZ (try different configuration but it does not work).
After a lot of attempt, I decided to give a try to [ConEmu](https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html).
Amazing, it works perfect. I can configure all my prefer behaviors like in ConsoleX, AND the bottom line is **maven now can display correctly like in native git bash**.

I think you can give a try to ConEmu.
This is the configuration for GitBash (it's quite same as ConsoleX)

Settings -> Startup -> Add new (+)

Task parameters

> /icon "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico" /dir E:\

Commands

> "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i

Remember to update your paths

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I migrated to ConEmu

Answer (score 3):

On Cygwin, when I pipe the output of Maven to the `tee` command, it fixes the output so that it displays the actual colored text instead of [←[1;34mINFO←[m] stuff:

`./mvnw -pl *-common -pl *jdbc-autoconfig dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework  | tee`

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [Lyle Z's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971169/7381844) answer I'm now using the following alias:

```
alias mvn="mvn_tee_output"
function mvn_tee_output () {
    "mvn" $@ | tee
}
```